# Footnotes in tables

Tags: tables, footnotes, parnotes

What is the best and simplest way to add footnotes in tables. I used \parnote but it did not give exactly what I am looking for. That is because I have three notes; two of them are same and should have same number and the third one is different.

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
A \parnote{aaa}     & 10 & 10  \\
B \parnote{aaa}     &   5 & 5  \\
C \parnote{bbb}     &   4 & 4  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\parnotes
```

Comment: Try `threeparttable`, please.

Comment: Where do you want the footnotes to show? Below the table, or at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I want the footnotes to show below the table.

Answer (score 0):

Two basic solutions (unless you're trying to do something especially fancy): either use `tabu` instead of `tabular`, or wrap the tabular in a `savenotes` environment.